# How can I generate a spy for an interface with Mockito without implementing a stub class?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

So I have the following interface:

```
public interface IFragmentOrchestrator {
    void replaceFragment(Fragment newFragment, AppAddress address);
}
```

How can I create a `spy` with [mockito](http://mockito.org/) that allows me to hook `ArgumentCaptor`-objects to calls to `replaceFragment()`?

I tried

```
    IFragmentOrchestrator orchestrator = spy(mock(IFragmentOrchestrator.class));
```

But mockito complains with "Mockito can only mock visible & non-final classes."

The only solution I've come up with so far is to implement an actual mock  of the interface before I create the `spy`. But that kind of defeats the purpose of a mocking framework:

```
public static class EmptyFragmentOrchestrator implements IFragmentOrchestrator {
    @Override
    public void replaceFragment(Fragment newFragment, AppAddress address) {

    }
}

public IFragmentOrchestrator getSpyObject() {
    return spy(new EmptyFragmentOrchestrator());
}
```

Am I missing something fundamental? I've been looking through [the docs](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/Mockito.html#3) without finding anything (but I may be blind).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spying is when you want to overlay stubbing over an existing implementation.  Here you have a bare interface, so it looks like you only need `mock`:

```
public class MyTest {
  @Captor private ArgumentCaptor<Fragment> fragmentCaptor;
  @Captor private ArgumentCaptor<AppAddress> addressCaptor;

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }

  @Test
  public void testThing() {
    IFragmentOrchestrator orchestrator = mock(IFragmentOrchestrator.class);

    // Now call some code which should interact with orchestrator 
    // TODO

    verify(orchestrator).replaceFragment(fragmentCaptor.capture(), addressCaptor.capture());

    // Now look at the captors
    // TODO
  }
}
```

If, on the other hand, you really are trying to spy on an implementation, then you should do that:

```
IFragmentOrchestrator orchestrator = spy(new IFragmentOrchestratorImpl());
```

This will call the actual methods on `IFragmentOrchestratorImpl`, but still allow interception with `verify`.

Comment: On my end, the verify call fails with `Wanted but not invoked` when I'm using mock instead of spy. Do I have a too old an version? (1.9.5)

Comment: Ahh.. goddamit I actually had to mock one of the methods in my interface to avoid NullPointerException. Your answer is correct :-)

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with `org.mockito.Mock` annotation

```java
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

public class Test {
    @Mock
    private TestInterface mockTestInterface;

    @Test
    public void testMethodShouldReturnTestString() {
        String testString = "Testing...";

        when(mockTestInterface.testMethod()).thenReturn(testString);

        assertThat(mockTestInterface.testMethod(), is(testString));
    }

}
```